# Tensorflow Object Detection not working, mAP low how to increase

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, object-detection, object-detection-api

Trying to get an object detector working to detect some fruit.
Initially tried on `ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29`. I ran for about 50k steps and the loss consistently showing around 2 [Total loss graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhHNk.png)
BUT mAP was 0.48 for 1 class and 0.16 for another [mAP results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IhvN.png)
In total I have 1936 images for training and 350 images for testing, so I'm not sure where I was going wrong as the dataset is not small.
All the images have been collected from images (https://github.com/openimages/dataset)

SSD config:

```
# SSD with Mobilenet v2 configuration for MSCOCO Dataset.
# Users should configure the fine_tune_checkpoint field in the train config as
# well as the label_map_path and input_path fields in the train_input_reader and
# eval_input_reader. Search for "PATH_TO_BE_CONFIGURED" to find the fields that
# should be configured.

model {
  ssd {
    num_classes: 2
    box_coder {
      faster_rcnn_box_coder {
        y_scale: 10.0
        x_scale: 10.0
        height_scale: 5.0
        width_scale: 5.0
      }
    }
    matcher {
      argmax_matcher {
        matched_threshold: 0.5
        unmatched_threshold: 0.5
        ignore_thresholds: false
        negatives_lower_than_unmatched: true
        force_match_for_each_row: true
      }
    }
    similarity_calculator {
      iou_similarity {
      }
    }
    anchor_generator {
      ssd_anchor_generator {
        num_layers: 6
        min_scale: 0.2
        max_scale: 0.95
        aspect_ratios: 1.0
        aspect_ratios: 2.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.5
        aspect_ratios: 3.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.3333
      }
    }
    image_resizer {
      fixed_shape_resizer {
        height: 300
        width: 300
      }
    }
    box_predictor {
      convolutional_box_predictor {
        min_depth: 0
        max_depth: 0
        num_layers_before_predictor: 0
        use_dropout: false
        dropout_keep_probability: 0.8
        kernel_size: 1
        box_code_size: 4
        apply_sigmoid_to_scores: false
        conv_hyperparams {
          activation: RELU_6,
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.00004
            }
          }
          initializer {
            truncated_normal_initializer {
              stddev: 0.03
              mean: 0.0
            }
          }
          batch_norm {
            train: true,
            scale: true,
            center: true,
            decay: 0.9997,
            epsilon: 0.001,
          }
        }
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: 'ssd_mobilenet_v2'
      min_depth: 16
      depth_multiplier: 1.0
      conv_hyperparams {
        activation: RELU_6,
        regularizer {
          l2_regularizer {
            weight: 0.00004
          }
        }
        initializer {
          truncated_normal_initializer {
            stddev: 0.03
            mean: 0.0
          }
        }
        batch_norm {
          train: true,
          scale: true,
          center: true,
          decay: 0.9997,
          epsilon: 0.001,
        }
      }
    }
    loss {
      classification_loss {
        weighted_sigmoid {
        }
      }
      localization_loss {
        weighted_smooth_l1 {
        }
      }
      hard_example_miner {
        num_hard_examples: 3000
        iou_threshold: 0.99
        loss_type: CLASSIFICATION
        max_negatives_per_positive: 3
        min_negatives_per_image: 3
      }
      classification_weight: 1.0
      localization_weight: 1.0
    }
    normalize_loss_by_num_matches: true
    post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 1e-8
        iou_threshold: 0.6
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 100
      }
      score_converter: SIGMOID
    }
  }
}

train_config: {
  batch_size: 24
  optimizer {
    rms_prop_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        exponential_decay_learning_rate {
          initial_learning_rate: 0.004
          decay_steps: 800720
          decay_factor: 0.95
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
      decay: 0.9
      epsilon: 1.0
    }
  }
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "E:/objectdetect/model/research/object_detection/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29/model.ckpt"
  fine_tune_checkpoint_type:  "detection"
  # Note: The below line limits the training process to 200K steps, which we
  # empirically found to be sufficient enough to train the pets dataset. This
  # effectively bypasses the learning rate schedule (the learning rate will
  # never decay). Remove the below line to train indefinitely.
  num_steps: 200000
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    ssd_random_crop {
    }
  }
}

train_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "E:/objectdetect/model/research/object_detection/train.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "E:/objectdetect/model/research/object_detection/training/labelmap.pbtxt"
}

eval_config: {
  num_examples: 67
  # Note: The below line limits the evaluation process to 10 evaluations.
  # Remove the below line to evaluate indefinitely.
  max_evals: 10
}

eval_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "E:/objectdetect/model/research/object_detection/test.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "E:/objectdetect/model/research/object_detection/training/labelmap.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_readers: 1
}
```

I then tried a similar test using Faster R-CNN instead as I thought the higher accuracy would work better, using `faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco_2018_01_28`

This time I have 3 classes. Comprises of 2731 images for training and 446 for testing.

Faster R-CNN config:

```
# Faster R-CNN with Inception v2, configured for Oxford-IIIT Pets Dataset.
# Users should configure the fine_tune_checkpoint field in the train config as
# well as the label_map_path and input_path fields in the train_input_reader and
# eval_input_reader. Search for "PATH_TO_BE_CONFIGURED" to find the fields that
# should be configured.

model {
  faster_rcnn {
    num_classes: 3
    image_resizer {
      keep_aspect_ratio_resizer {
        min_dimension: 600
        max_dimension: 1024
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: 'faster_rcnn_inception_v2'
      first_stage_features_stride: 16
    }
    first_stage_anchor_generator {
      grid_anchor_generator {
        scales: [0.25, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
        aspect_ratios: [0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
        height_stride: 16
        width_stride: 16
      }
    }
    first_stage_box_predictor_conv_hyperparams {
      op: CONV
      regularizer {
        l2_regularizer {
          weight: 0.0
        }
      }
      initializer {
        truncated_normal_initializer {
          stddev: 0.01
        }
      }
    }
    first_stage_nms_score_threshold: 0.0
    first_stage_nms_iou_threshold: 0.7
    first_stage_max_proposals: 300
    first_stage_localization_loss_weight: 2.0
    first_stage_objectness_loss_weight: 1.0
    initial_crop_size: 14
    maxpool_kernel_size: 2
    maxpool_stride: 2
    second_stage_box_predictor {
      mask_rcnn_box_predictor {
        use_dropout: false
        dropout_keep_probability: 1.0
        fc_hyperparams {
          op: FC
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.0
            }
          }
          initializer {
            variance_scaling_initializer {
              factor: 1.0
              uniform: true
              mode: FAN_AVG
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    second_stage_post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 0.0
        iou_threshold: 0.6
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 300
      }
      score_converter: SOFTMAX
    }
    second_stage_localization_loss_weight: 2.0
    second_stage_classification_loss_weight: 1.0
  }
}

train_config: {
  batch_size: 1
  optimizer {
    momentum_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        manual_step_learning_rate {
          initial_learning_rate: 0.0002
          schedule {
            step: 900000
            learning_rate: .00002
          }
          schedule {
            step: 1200000
            learning_rate: .000002
          }
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
    }
    use_moving_average: false
  }
  gradient_clipping_by_norm: 10.0
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "/homes/nj303/objectdetect/model/research/object_detection/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco_2018_01_28/model.ckpt"
  from_detection_checkpoint: true
  load_all_detection_checkpoint_vars: true
  # Note: The below line limits the training process to 200K steps, which we
  # empirically found to be sufficient enough to train the pets dataset. This
  # effectively bypasses the learning rate schedule (the learning rate will
  # never decay). Remove the below line to train indefinitely.
  num_steps: 200000
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
}


train_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "/homes/nj303/objectdetect/model/research/object_detection/train.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "/homes/nj303/objectdetect/model/research/object_detection/training/labelmap.pbtxt"
}

eval_config: {
  metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"
  num_examples: 67
}

eval_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "/homes/nj303/objectdetect/model/research/object_detection/test.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "/homes/nj303/objectdetect/model/research/object_detection/training/labelmap.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_readers: 1
}
```

However I am still receiving poor results in terms of mAP.
I have ran for 100k steps and the loss is ranging is below 0.1 however the mAP is 0.38! I'm not sure how to improve this? [mAP results for Faster R-CNN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITzTb.png)

I'm new to this so any help would be appreciated! I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: Did you try to shuffle the images when you create the tf records. May be try to train model more like 200K steps, do check that the data is not overfitting.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, dataset size depends on perspective, for your goal might be good enought but for other goals might be really small.

Second, as you can see on the pipeline config for ssd there is a note:

> Note: The below line limits the training process to 200K steps, which we empirically found to be sufficient enough to train the pets dataset. This effectively bypasses the learning rate schedule (the learning rate willnever decay). Remove the below line to train indefinitely.

Pets dataset has 37 categories and 200 images per category (7400 images), not a big number, but How they achieve good results? The answer is on the steps, they used 200k steps, this gives the network the enough time to stabilize on mAP and get more features from the training dataset.

So I suggest you to try this:

- Increase the number of your steps, you can start testing with 100K and see how much it improves.
- Augmentate your dataset to generate more images from yout dataset, with more light, darker, out of focus, different background, etc. I recommend you to use this library: https://github.com/aleju/imgaug
- Also mAP is a good way to know how your network will perform but I recommend you to make real tests with some objects, and you will see in which case doesn't work, e.g. my objects is detected correctly on white backgrounds but fails when the background is green or red. This means that you need to have more variety of backgrounds for your objects. Another example, my object is detected when i'm 30 cm closer to it but is not detected when i'm 50cm from it. This means that your dataset need more images from far away.

Comment: In my case, the more I increase the num_steps parameter the less steps in the training.. Idk what I am missing? it is confusing